# how to pass parent object as parameter to a constructor of child class

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

In the below code i have a couple of questions to be asked:
i am unable to pass object of class `Address` as a parameter to the constructor of its child class `EmployeeAddress`. Why so ? It is giving error like parameter mismatch ..no parameters passed....
I want to call the `Address` object  from the class `EmployeeAddress` in show method. How to do that?

```
class Address {
    public String street;
    int pin;
    String city;

    Address(String street, int pin, String city) {
        this.street = street;
        this.pin = pin;
        this.city = city;
    }
}

class EmployeeAddress extends Address {
    int empid;
    public String empname;
    Address add;

    EmployeeAddress (int empid, String empname, Address add){
        this.empid = empid;
        this.empname = empname;
        this.add = add;
    }

    void show() {
        System.out.println("my name is " + empname + "and my empid is " + empid);
    }
}

class Employee {

    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        Address ad1 = new Address("mystreet", 201301, "nyk");

        EmployeeAddress a1 = new EmployeeAddress(123, "kin", ad1);

        a1.show();
    }

    /*
     * public String toString() { return
     * "my name is "+a1.empname+"and my pin is "+ad1.pin ; }
     */
}
```

Comment: *Please.* Improve your formatting and naming such that it is adheres to the Java Coding Style Conventions.

Comment: What method of Address do you want to call in test?

Comment: Why do you want to pass parent object as parameter to child? Its a very bad design. I would suggest to rather change your design

Comment: Renamed `class test` into `class EmployeeAddress`. Following a good naming convention practices (inheritanced + capitalization)

Comment: Except `EmployeeAddress.add` which is wrong usage of inheritance, this behavior is very similar to down casting but with an extra arguments to create a specialization from a general object. It happens when you have a limited information during the creation time to create the specializations object. Whether it is good or bad, I believe this pattern is acceptable. Alternative to this approach is to use **Composition Pattern**, but there are times where Composition just doesn't fit into your situation, and you still need this pattern.

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of issues here, the most critical of which is [correctly pointed out by Belerafon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23309325/2187042), the lack of a parent class constructor (either creating a no-arguments constructor in the parent or calling one of the existing constructors as super(street,pin,city), probably you want to call the super(street,pin,city) constructor).

## Lack of a default constructor, or calling an appropriate constructor

Class test(sic) *is* an address because it extends Address. As such it must satisfy the contract of Address; i.e. you can use it as if it were an Address. Address has only one constructor `Address(String street, int pin, String city)` which initialises it such that all its methods can be called without error. So you need to call the appropriate super constructor, so

```
test(int empid, String empname, Address add){
    super(add.street, add.pin, add.city); //<-- this gives the parent part of the class all the information it needs
    this.empid = empid;
    this.empname = empname;
    this.add = add; //<-- somewhat strange, covered later
}
```

## Passing a parent class in the constructor of a child class and keeping the reference

This can have legitimate uses but in this case I fear it is being used inappropriately. In this case class `test` both *is* an address and *contains* a different address. An analogy for when this would be appropriate is that a `Female Cat` both is a `Cat` and can also contains cats in the form of kittens.

Most probably you either don't want to extend address at all, or you want to stop passing an Address to the constructor (depending on if class `test` *is an* address or *contains an* address . So:

<sup>In these examples I have used the correct Java naming conventions, see below</sup>

```
class Test{
    int empid;
    public String empname;
    Address add;

    Test(int empid, String empname, Address add){
        this.empid = empid;
        this.empname = empname;
        this.add = add;
    }

    void show() {
        System.out.println("my name is " + empname + "and my empid is " + empid);
    }
}
```

or

```
class Test extends Address {
    int empid;
    public String empname;


    Test(int empid, String empname, String street, int pin, String city){
        super(street, pin, city); //<-- this gives the parent part of the class all the information it needs
        this.empid = empid;
        this.empname = empname;

    }

    void show() {
        System.out.println("my name is " + empname + "and my empid is " + empid);
    }
}
```

## Poor use of Java Coding Style Conventions

Class names start with a capital letter. Object variable names start with a small letter. As such class `test` should be `Test`. People will have no end of problems reading your code if you  do not stick to these conventions.

After a long think I realise `empid` is probably `employeeID`. These sorts of abbrevations are also against the Style Conventions as they make code painfully difficult to read, use complete words except in exceptional circumstances (e.g. HTML, since the accronym is more well known than HyperTextMarkupLanguage). This would also suggest that class `test` is actually `EmployeeDetails`. In which case it is not an address and should not extend address, it should however encapsulate (contain) an address.

Comment: I've renamed `class test` to `class EmployeeAddress` in the question.

Comment: Just to share, when you don't extend `Address`, this is a good alternative solution to the problem. And In Fact, it is what we know as a **Composition Pattern**

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that class Address does not have a default constructor defined. In the constructor of `EmployeeAddress` java tries to call for a parameterless constructor of Address since Address is a parent class. But it cannot because there is no perameterless constructor in Address. Adding one would solve the problem